# JSF 1.2 + JBoss 5 not rendering jsf tags.

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm trying to convert a .net app to JSF 1.2 to sit on our legacy JBoss server and I can't get the jsf tags to render. In my browser i see exactly what i see in eclipse.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         version="2.5">
  <display-name>WebDataViewer</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tlds/formatter-taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <context-param>     
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>     
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>     
    </context-param> 

    <context-param>     
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>     
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>     
    </context-param> 

    <context-param>     
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>     
        <param-value>server</param-value>     
    </context-param>  

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>CLASSIC</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>     
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>    
    </listener>    

    <!-- Allows you to put html comments in your views without the compiler blowing up -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <application>
        <view-handler>org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler</view-handler>
    </application>

    <!-- Backing Beans -->  
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>tableBacking</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>edu.mayo.ccs.webdataviewer.ui.backing.TableLookupBacking</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">Web Data Viewer</ui:define>

        <ui:define name="centerColumn">
            <h1>Web Data Viewer</h1>                                
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Comment: To avoid the obvious, you're opening the page by `/index.jsf` or `/faces/index.xhtml` (so that the `FacesServlet` is invoked as per its URL mapping) and not by `/index.xhtml`, right?

Comment: I've tried them all and i get the same result

Comment: Oh? So `/faces/index.xhtml` also gives the raw source code?

Comment: Downvote with no comment as to why?

Comment: It wasn't me, but it's most likely because your question is a bit too much like an effortless "Please debug my code". Anyway, I'm still not sure. I'd initially suspect the Facelets configuration. Is that `facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS` really necessary? Are you mixing Facelets with JSP? I'd first create a completely blank Facelets project with an absolute minimum of web.xml and faces-config.xml and without any RichFaces stuff, based on [Facelets 1.x' own docbook](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html), and get that to run. Then, add/configure RichFaces in steps until it breaks.

Comment: Well if you call 3 straight days of an effortless please debug my code then fair enough. I've started with a blank project and these things are all things that i've added along the way trying to get this thing to work.

Comment: So, without RichFaces (and thus having the project in its absolute minimum trim) it didn't work either?

Comment: Just re-removed every piece of rich faces from web.xml, pom.xml, index.xhtml, and template.xhtml and still seeing source in the browser.

Comment: Do i somehow have to link up facelets? I have jboss-faces.jar in my User Libraries on the Project Facets -> Java Server Faces in my properties.

Comment: Have you followed the Facelets docbook? I'm not sure what RichFaces all is doing or is requiring, but Facelets' own `FaceletViewHandler` is missing in your `faces-config.xml`. Again, see the docbook for the minimum required `web.xml` and `faces-config.xml` entries.

Comment: Yes i have followed that. I've tried many times adding the view handler to my faces-config file and when i do, it gives me the warning `cannot find fully qualified class: com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, you're getting the following exception while configuring Facelets 1.x as per their own [docbook](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html):

> cannot find fully qualified class: com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler

Apparently JBoss 5.x doesn't ship with Facelets 1.x out the box (could be very good as it's not part of standard Java EE 5). You'd need to provide it yourself in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. You can get it from the Maven repository among others [here](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/thirdparty-releases/com.sun.facelets/jsf-facelets/1.1.15). It's the `jsf-facelets.jar` file.

Note that this file is not required for JSF 2.x as Facelets libraries are bundled in the JSF JAR itself.

Comment: That was it. I guess i hadn't included the facelets jar. I had tried earlier to use the maven link that you posted and I was getting errors when running maven install. It wasn't able to get dependency facelets.jar. not sure what the deal was there. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: So after looking at this again, apparently my problem is not resolved. I can see in my maven dependencies that i have `jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar` file, but i'm still seeing the error `cannot find fully qualified class: com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler` in my faces-config.xml file.

Comment: Sorry, Maven is beyond me. All you need to make sure is that it puts that JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the built WAR. The exception tells that it is not there. How to tell Maven to do so is a second.

Comment: Basically i have built my project and it has pulled in the facelets.jar. That is why it's showing in my maven dependencies folder.

Comment: This question+answer is maybe helpful, even though it does not make much sense to me how `<compile>` plays a role here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503880/unable-to-find-class-com-sun-facelets-faceletviewhandler  (I found it by just [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=maven%20cannot%20find%20fully%20qualified%20class%3A%20com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler) your exact error message along with keyword "Maven")

Comment: Ahh wait i was hitting /index.xhtml instead of /index.jsf. Your solution does work....Monday morning..

Comment: You're welcome, even though I'm not remotely sure how missing the `FacesServlet` mapping would ever produce this error. A clean/build/deploy failure is more likely the cause.